# Database link creation from sql server 2005 to postgresql 8.3.12 on windows xp sp2

Tags: sql-server-2005, postgresql

I want to create the database link from sql server 2005 to postgresql 8.3.12 on windows xp sp2 machine to tranfer one of table data from sql server to postgressql, here in both the databases the table structure is same kindly help me getting this done and best way to do this

Answer (score 1):

I think this theoretically is possible using MS Access 2007 (and possibly other versions, but I've only used 2007) and hooking postgresql up [as an ODBC](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) data source.

In MS Access, right click on the table and select "Export -> Export to ODBC database"

I was not too long ago trying to migrate an Access database this way, but ran into complications so ended up doing things manually (exporting data as CSV, create new tables manually, and then importing the CSV data via a script). I think the complications were peculiar to the old source database though, and this the above method *should* have worked.